# Different Results from HTTP calls to angular2-in-memory-web-api with the same collection name

Tags: http, angular

I am trying to use angular2-in-memory-web-api in my angular 2 project. I'm having trouble finding any documentation that shows how to return different data objects for different requests with the same collection name. I believe the class I use for my SEED_DATA is off but I'm not sure how to structure it the right way to get what I want.

Here is my main.ts

```
import {provide} from "@angular/core";
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {SEED_DATA, InMemoryBackendService} from "angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service";
import {AppTestData} from "./AppTestData";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: InMemoryBackendService}),
    provide(SEED_DATA, {useClass: AppTestData})
]);
```

My AppTestData.ts file would look something like this

```
export class AppTestData {
    createDb() {
        let studentData = {
            name: "Student Name",
            grade: "B"
        };
        let otherStudentData = {
            name: "Other Student Name",
            grade: "A"
        };


        let httpPaths = {
            somepath: {
                student: studentData,
                anotherPath: {
                    student: otherStudentData
                }
            }
        }
        return httpPaths;
    }
}
```

My attempt at the httpPaths object is off. But the idea would be me calling a get http call to "something/student" and getting back studentData and calling another get http call to "something/anotherPath/student" and getting back otherStudentData.

The following does seem to work but I would like to specify my complete path incase I want post to “something/student” and “something/anotherPath/student” and get different results.

```
let httpPaths = {
            student: studentData
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you missed the brackets in the return statement:

```
return {httpPaths};
```

The developer created an example which can be found [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/event-view)

Comment: If you notice he has rooms, speakers, and sessions as their own objects, then he wraps them in {} before returning. I did the same except I specified the keys and put them in their own variable before returning. Say he had an "api/room/save" and an "api/speakers/save" url that he wanted to call and return an object. He would have to make a save object and only return that one save object for both of the calls. I would like to know how he could return his speaker object or his room object on those save calls instead of the save object.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "mock" two different databases you have to follow this syntax:

```
export class AppTestData {
    createDb() {
        let heroes = {
            name: "Batman",
            city: "Gotham"
        };
        let countries = {
            name: "America",
            code: "GR"
        };

        return {heroes,countries};
    }
}
```

In your service you can consume it with a Promise and the url for the http request would be :
`private httpUrl = '../contacts/contacts';`

My file structure is something like:

```
repo
 -app
  -shared
   myservice.ts       // this consumes the data from the InMemory DB
   data.service.db.ts // this implements the InMemoryDbService
  ...
```

At least that's how I solved the problem.
Indeed the official documentation is poor so far.